# How to select a column with max value of other column, and all corresponding rows of column in another table?

Tags: mysql, join, max

**Two given tables:**

[image: Students table]

[image: Activities table]

Question: Select the activity with the highest cost and the names of the students that are registered in it.

Result should be: activity column(golf) and students column(mark antony).
In this case there's just one student registered but I want to account for a case if there are more students registered.

I tried all kinds of solutions but I cant seem to get it right.

Any tips appreciated, thanks.

edit: I see Im getting downvoted, I didnt want to show what I tried because I think its way off the mark but here is some of it:

```
SELECT s.Student, a.Activity from Activities as a inner join Students as s 
ON a.ID = s.ID where a.Cost = (select max(a.Cost))

SELECT s.Student, a.cost, a.Activity from Activities as a inner join Students `as s ON a.ID = s.ID`
group by s.Student having a.cost = max(a.cost)
```

Comment: no you got downvoted because of the images see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query works.

But please next time [don't use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) and you should also take a look at [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE activity (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `Activity` VARCHAR(8),
>   `Cost` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO activity
>   (`ID`, `Activity`, `Cost`)
> VALUES
>   ('84', 'Swimming', '17'),
>   ('84', 'Tennis', '36'),
>   ('100', 'Squash', '40'),
>   ('100', 'Swimming', '17'),
>   ('182', 'Tennis', '36'),
>   ('219', 'Golf', '47'),
>   ('219', 'Swimming', '15'),
>   ('219', 'Squash', '40');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE students (
>   `Student` VARCHAR(11),
>   `ID` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO students
>   (`Student`, `ID`)
> VALUES
>   ('John Smith', '84'),
>   ('Jane Bloggs', '100'),
>   ('John Smith', '182'),
>   ('Mark Antor', '219');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT Student,Activity
> FROM  students s INNER JOIN (
> SELECT id,Activity FROm activity WHERE Cost = (SELECT MAX(Cost) FROM activity)) a ON s.ID = a.id
> ```
>
> ```
> Student    | Activity
> :--------- | :-------
> Mark Antor | Golf
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c979a201edcfe59345443629999ec48d)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I read more about that technique you used - A join between a table and another table by the use of select in parenthesis? Is there a name for that?

Comment: Hey, I learned about sub queries and I tried solving this exercise once more by memory and I wrote this and it worked:

select s.Student, a.activity from Students s inner join Activities a
on s.id = a.id 
where a.cost = (select max(a.Cost) from Activities a)

Are there any problems with doing it my way? for example going forward is your way more efficient etc in terms of performance etc?

Comment: there is no difference in the result, but i reduce the number of cloumns before it is getting joined and you reduce the number after joining